Rearrange 1D Array Quickly
I have about one billion 1D arrays that I need to rearrange:
import numpy as np

N = 2**24  # The length of each 1D array is always a power of 2
x = np.random.rand(N)  # Imagine having many, many of these of differing lengths
n = int(np.sqrt(N))

x[:] = np.transpose(x.reshape(n, n)).ravel()

One possibility of speeding this up is using numba:
from numba import njit

@njit(fastmath=True)
def rearrange(x, n):
  for k in range(n):
    for p in range(k + 1, n):
      i = k + p * n
      j = p + k * n

      x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]

Or maybe there is a lower cost, super fast way of accomplishing this with stride_tricks?

Also, overwriting the original 1D array is NOT a requirement if it can help improve performance (i.e., the time to create the output array actually opens up our options to other algorithms/approaches)
